# loop and parse apart of a string from a file dos

Tags: for-loop, scripting, batch-file, dos, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to parse a word from a line on a commandline with DOS command

if the string contains _(" then I want to store it in a file.
example:

```
   js\.svn\text:        $errors=      '</b> - ' . _("LABEL") . ' '      . _('ERR
```

if it doesn't, then I want to ignore it any move on.

I'm having a hard time trying to figure out how the delim works or if i should even use it for this. I see lots of examples on outputting a whole line, but not a string.

OR... i was thinking could look through a for loop through each word until there isn't any more in the line.... and if the word beginning matches _(" then i'll output it in a file?

something like this?

```
 for /F "tokens=1*" %%i in (get_list.txt) do(
   for %%A in (%%j) do(
      if (%%A == "_("")) >> get_id.txt
  )
 )
```

Can someone correct my syntax or guide me in any way?

Comment: might have more luck on Superuser.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

After re-reading your question, I'm not entirely sure what you want.  Are you saying you want the *entire line* dumped into a text file, not just the matches?

I'm also not clear about something else.  Does `get_list.txt` contain the PHP-ish code, or does it contain a list of files you want to check for the PHP-ish code?

If `get_list.txt` is the code and you want matching lines dumped out to `get_id.txt`, then all you need is `findstr "_(" "get_list.txt" >> "get_id.txt"`.

---

The following answers were submitted upon my original assumption that all you wanted in `get_id.txt` were the exact matches, for instance, the word `match` in the string _("`match`".

---

**Path 1**

Well, if I were you, I'd use [grep -o](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm) to do this.  It can be done with a for loop, but it can be done much more easily with grep.

```
grep -P -o "(?<=_\([\'\"])\w+" get_list.txt >> get_id.txt
```

... if what you're capturing will always be enclosed in quotation marks, or...

```
grep -P -o "(?<=_\()[^\)]+" get_list.txt | grep -P -o "\w+" >> get_id.txt
```

... if there might be some un-quoted integers, booleans, or other non-quoted data types.

---

**Path 2**

If you insist on using plain batch scripting, then the second most efficient thing would be to use a JScript hybrid script to take advantage of JScript's regexp matching.

```
@if (@x==@y) @end /*

:: batch portion

@echo off
setlocal
for /f "delims=" %%I in ('findstr "_(" "get_list.txt"') do (
    cscript /nologo /e:jscript "%~f0" %%I >> get_id.txt
)

goto :EOF

:: JScript portion */
var m=WSH.arguments(0).match(/_\([\'\"]?\w+/g);
for (var i=0; i<m.length; i++ ) {
    WSH.echo(m[i].replace(/_\([\'\"]?/,''));
}
```

---

**Path 3**

If you truly want to parse the text file word-by-word as in your example, this is the syntax you're looking for I think.  If your text files are large, I think this will be the slowest solution, as batch for loops can be very slow at times.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "delims=" %%I in ('findstr "_(" "get_list.txt"') do (
    for %%x in (%%I) do (
        set word=%%x
        set word=!word:_^(=!
        if not !word!==%%x (
            set word=!word:"=!
            set word=!word:'=!
            >> get_id.txt echo !word:^)=!
        )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

No external utility nor "FOR" is required. Try this line:

```
 >get_id.txt findstr _(\" get_list.txt
```

The \ "escapes" the Quotesign.
The following line will NOT work:

```
 findstr _(\" get_list.txt >get_id.txt
```